# Truecrypt encrypted Win 7 HDD in a Mac

Tags: windows-7, macos, boot-camp, truecrypt

I'm new here, but I'd like to see if anyone can point me in the right direction for a tutorial of how to do this:

I have a work computer that has win7 with TrueCrypt full system encryption - I want to replace the computer with a Mac, but I need to continue running Windows for work purposes.

What I'd like to do is get a Macbook and install two HDDs in it - one with OSx on it (an SSD if possible to save space and weight) and my Win 7 HDD - the idea is that I just pull the HDD from my current laptop and stick it in the Mac that's set up for this.  I can't change anything with the existing HDD - can't use Bitlocker or something.

I don't mind to spend money on software that might be needed.

First of all, is this possible?

Secondly, can anyone help me with a basic outline of what I'd need to do, what software to buy, etc?

Thank you to anyone who answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to install two internal drives on macbook nor iMac.

If you want to use the currently encrypted drive, then I would suggest using it in the external drive enclosure connected to mac (via thunderbolt 2 or USB 3.0 ports - with other options the drive will perform slower, more info [here](https://superuser.com/a/138854/578626)) while running Virtual Machine (VM) with Windows. What means that on your new mac you need to install similar to [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/) (e.g. [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/)) virtualization software in order to be able run Windows and use your encrypted drive.

To sum up, you'll need:

- Drive enclosure
- Virtualization software
- Copy of the version of Windows you want